Should insulation be removed between heated and unheated spaces?
I have built a small cabin, insulated using 100 mm of glass wool. The construction follows a standard design: wooden boards on the interior, a vapor barrier, insulation within a timber frame, a facade membrane, and an external timber facade. The cabin is heated with a small 4 kW boat oven, which keeps it very warm during the winter.
Now, I plan to add even smaller, insulated extension for a toilet and storage area. My idea is to use some of the heat from the main cabin to warm this new space since the cabin gets quite hot in winter (more than I want).
Would it be feasible to remove the insulation from the cabin wall that adjoins the new room and create two openings—one at the top and one at the bottom in the wood between—for heat exchange? In this setup, the wall between the two rooms would consist of wooden boards with a vapor barrier and an air gap in place of the insulation.


why not add a door directly to the toilet? that big uninsulated hole will do plenty for heat exchange?

Why is the toilet constructed with a separate outside door? I suspect it's a long drop and you want it ventilated. Then you wouldn't want openings in the wall between it and the cabin. But with the mention of vapour barrier I wonder if you mean holes only from the cabin side into the cavity.

Water and warm air is good.  Water can do nasty stuff if allowed to freeze.  If the cabin is allowed to go without heat for some time, you will need a way to drain all the water or use plumbing anti-freeze, if using a toilet that uses water.

Is this addition a glorified outhouse? In that case the design makes sense, although ventilation requirements means that air loss will make the cabin much harder to heat evenly. Insulate it but control the amount of air entering the new space with a sealable register.

It is not possible to add a door that leads directly to the outhouse (because small space).

You say the new extension is "not heated" but in point of fact, you are proposing to heat it (by moving air from the heated cabin to the insulated but without its own stove addition.) So then it is heated, just indirectly. There's not much point in retaining a vapor barrier in the wall between the two - what you do want to do is make sure the vapor barrier is properly joined where the new addition meets the existing heated cabin. Given one purpose of the new addition, you might also want an exhaust fan in there...The drawing says WC but if it's actually an outhouse that's entirely different.

You really don't want air exchange with an outhouse/pit toilet arrangement. There are other ways to move heat.

Well, there is a door and a windows which could be use to ventilate after... you know. So that is not of a big concern. The main question is if I should leave the insulation in the wall between cabin and outhouse or take it out.

What you really want is an electrically heated toilet seat for the winter. This increases the comfort while maintaining hygiene.
